# Changing referer from ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to change referer from ajax POST data. I want to call ajax from my local computer but it referrer to another domain.

How I can Change? Is it possible

**Code :**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url_here",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Referer": "Change here reference"
    },
    data: {
        data1: "somedata"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

(Almost?) All browser will overwrite that field, so it is not possible to set from jQuery's ajax (or javascript in general).